# How to open a graphics device on another monitor using R

Tags: r

I use a Windows OS and work with three monitors arranged as follows:

```
  3
2 1
```

I code on window 1, run the R console on window 2, and have other reference material in window 3.  At present when I open a graphics device in R it defaults to window 1, and I would prefer it to open by default on window 3, where it less likely to get lost behind the code.

I have tried:

`windows()` with `xpos` and `ypos` parameters, but this only permits repositioning on window 1.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure R doesn't have any control over this.  You need to consult the documentation for your display drivers.  The display drivers for my work PC have a setting that controls on which screen new windows are displayed.

Comment: Software (e.g. virtualbox) can control internally what monitor it displays on.  Presumably, then, this requires some lower level command of things than R can natively achieve.